# Internal Server Error in some pages in website hosted at Parallels Plesk panel

Tags: plesk, parallels

I hosted my new website in Parallels Plesk panel. this is the url [http://www.lifestylebiz.in]. There is an 'Internal Server Error' in some pages all other pages are working. Could you please help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web server logs and let us know what exact error are you getting in logs file. Might be there is an issues with the permission OR php setting.